# How to do custom list grouping based on variable?

Tags: python, list, grouping, list-comprehension

Say I have a list that gets generated such as:

```
list_x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Then I divide it up like this:

```
list_x = [01,23,45,67,89]
```

with this list comprehension:

```
list_x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
grp_count = 2
new_list = map(int, [list_x[i+0]+list_x[i+1] for i in range(0, len(list_x)-1, grp_count)])
```

How can I make this code so I can group it into a grouping based on `grp_count'

for example if `group_count = 5`:

```
list_x = [01234,56789]
```

I know I have to insert multiple `list_x[i+n]` for each addition of grouping size somehow.

Comment: Your code gives `1,5,9,13,17`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Python doesn't display the leading zeros of integers like that by default.

Comment: What should be the returnformat: strings (list of chars in python) in a list? O tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` to do the trick like this example:

```
def grouper(a, num):
    if num > int(len(a)/2):
        return []
    # If you need to return only a list of lists use:
    # return [a[k:k+num] for k in range(0, len(a), num)]
    return ["".join(map(str, a[k:k+num])) for k in range(0, len(a), num)]

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(grouper(a, 2))
print(grouper(a, 5))
```

Output:

```
['01', '23', '45', '67', '89']
['01234', '56789']
```

Comment: The line with the return is very readable and totaly easy to understand... not

Comment: You're welcome. Glade that this answer is helping you. Happy coding.

Comment: **edited over 5 min**: This works great without new imports. Thanks!
I'm still trying to comprehend the return with the nested loop in the function. Seems complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like the itertools grouper recipe from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

then

```
list_x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(list(grouper(list_x, 5, 0)))
```

gives

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, there's no way to create a list of integers in Python that would display like `[01234,56789]` because Python doesn't show the value of integers with a leading zero like that. The closest you could get is `[1234, 56789]`.

However you can create a list of **strings** with those digits in them like this:

```
def grouper(n, iterable):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

list_x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
grp_count = 5
new_list = [''.join(map(str, g)) for g in grouper(grp_count, list_x)]
print(new_list)  #-> ['01234', '56789']
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you using `*[iter(iterable)]*n` inside of `zip()` ? I didn't get the reason behind. Thanks.

Comment: @Chiheb: Why? Because, used as arguments to `zip()`, it's a compact way to create an iterator that will return elements from its second argument in groups of `n` items. Is that what you want to know? Perhaps it would be a little more understandable if written as `*([iter(iterable)]*n)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's the first time i see a piece of code like yours. And i think that i didn't get it well even After your comment. I'll try to meditate on your answer and try to understand they way you used to solve this current question. Thanks a lot for your comment. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Chiheb: You're welcome. It's almost identical to a similarly named recipe in the [**Itertools Recipes**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=grouper#itertools-recipes) section of the documentation for the `itertools` module. Also note that the first `*` in the expression is using something called "[argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)" to pass multiple arguments to the `zip()` function.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks for the links.